# Android: toggle screen auto brightness temporarily

Tags: android, brightness

I want to disable the automatic brightness (I want to prevent the screen from being turned off), but only when my application is active (when the Activity is running).

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onResume()`, use the [`PowerManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) to obtain either a [`SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK), a [`SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK) or a [`FULL_WAKE_LOCK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK). In `onPause()`, release the wake lock. You will need the [`WAKE_LOCK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK) permission.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your Activity

```
protected void onResume() {
    // Disables power-saving
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    super.onResume();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    // Enables power-saving
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```